# MVC 5 Code First Editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, character

Hey guys  i am coding in MVC 5  code first  now i have this table below  when i want to edit a Cell number or an email and my changes are saved on the database my Picture got deleted i do not know why because i did not change it. every time i Edit other information the Picture got delete when i save my changes

```
[Key]
public int Member_Id { get; set; }
[Required]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Please enter minimum of 3 characters")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s?]+$", ErrorMessage = "Pease enter valid name!")]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s?]+$", ErrorMessage = "Pease enter valid Surname!")]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Please enter minimum of 3 characters")]
[Display(Name = "Surname")]
public string Surname { get; set; }
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^(\d{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Cellphone number  must be 10 digits!")]
[Display(Name = "Cell Number")]
public string Cell_Number { get; set; }
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^(\d{13})$", ErrorMessage = "id must be 13 digits!")]
[Display(Name = "ID Number")]
public string ID_Number { get; set; }
[Required]
[RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
[Display(Name = "Email Address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Physical Address")]
public string Address { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Owner")]
public bool Owner { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Driver")]
public bool Driver { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Rank Manager")]
public bool Rank_Manager { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Profile Picture")]
public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
public string alter_Text { get; set; }
public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Taxi> Taxi { get; set; }
```

and this is my controller

```
public ActionResult EditPick(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Member member = db.Member.Find(id);
    if (member == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(member);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditPick(/*[Bind(Include = "Member_Id,Name,Surname,Cell_Number,ID_Number,Email,Address,Owner,Driver,Rank_Manager,Picture,alter_Text,ImageMimeType")]*/ Member member,HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    try
    {

            var picturee = new Member();

            if (image != null)
            {
                if (image.ContentLength > 2 * 1024 * 1024)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "The File size be not more than 2 MB");
                    return View();
                }
                if (!(image.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || image.ContentType == "image/gif"))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "The File Allowed : jpeg and gif");
                    return View();

                }
                if (image != null)
                {
                    member.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                    member.Picture = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                    image.InputStream.Read(member.Picture, 0, image.ContentLength);
                }
            }
            picturee.Member_Id = member.Member_Id;
            picturee.Name = member.Name;
            picturee.Surname = member.Surname;
            picturee.Cell_Number = member.Cell_Number;
            picturee.ID_Number = member.ID_Number;
            picturee.Email = member.Email;
            picturee.Address = member.Address;
            picturee.Owner = member.Owner;
            picturee.Driver = member.Driver;
            picturee.Rank_Manager = member.Rank_Manager;
            picturee.Picture = member.Picture;
            picturee.ImageMimeType = member.ImageMimeType;
            picturee.alter_Text = member.alter_Text;



            db.Entry(picturee).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
         catch (DataException)
    {

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Sorry can not update contact Administrator");


    }

    return View(member);
}
```

This is my View when posting

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Member</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Member_Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cell_Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cell_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cell_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Owner, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Owner)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Owner, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Driver, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Driver)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Driver, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rank_Manager, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rank_Manager)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rank_Manager, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Picture, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @{
    if (Model.Picture != null)
    {
        string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Picture);
        string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
        <img src="@imageSrc" width="100" height="100" />
    }
            }
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Picture, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.alter_Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.alter_Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.alter_Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageMimeType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageMimeType, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageMimeType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show the view cshtml. And in particular how do you Post the form.

Comment: @Steve I have added my View ,Please help

Comment: To post a file to your controller you need to have an Input=File with Name=Image The fact that you display the image on your view doesn't mean that the view can post it back as a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, you need to add a `Input=File Name=Image` in your view to post back the file with the changes to your profile picture, but the most important thing to do, is to read back the member info from you database and not build a new one instance of a member.
Actually your new member has no info on the previous image if the view don't post back a file and when you save you loose the image bytes.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditPick(Member member,HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    try
    {
        var picturee = new context.Member.Find(member.Member_Id);
        if(picturee != null)
        {
            .....
        }
        // Now you can start updating the other fields and then save.
        // This is not needed -> picturee.Member_Id = member.Member_Id;
        picturee.Name = member.Name;
        picturee.Surname = member.Surname;
        ....
```

In this way you reload the image bytes in case the View don't post back a file to read

In the view you need to add the appriate code to post back the profile image if the user want it updated.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Picture, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
          <input name="Image" type="file" />
     </div> 
    @{
        if (Model.Picture != null)
        {
           string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Picture);
           string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
          <img src="@imageSrc" width="100" height="100" />
        }
     }
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Picture, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

</div>
```